# Parameterize SBT DockerPlugin from command line

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

I'm using SBT for building a Scala application and we are using the DockerPlugin to do the actual build. The configuration looks something like this:

```
 .enablePlugins(PlayScala, PlayAkkaHttp2Support, DockerPlugin)
  .in(...)
  .settings(name := "...")
  .settings(version := VERSION)
  ...
  .settings(dockerUpdateLatest := true)
```

So I run `sbt docker:publish` from our CI server (CircleCI in this case). But this builds and publishes a version to our Docker repository. Thing is we run this both on `develop` and on `master`. Develop gets a suffix `-SNAPSHOT` but both push their versioned Docker image as latest tag.

And that last thing is something I don't want, for master I want to make a build (eg. 1.5.3 and push it to latest (cause that's my latest stable release)) but not for develop. So I was thinking to set `.settings(dockerUpdateLatest := false)` to not auto update latest but then in my `master` build configure something on the command line to trigger/change that setting.

Is that something that is feasible, and can someone tell me how or where to look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Java system property.

```scala
dockerUpdateLatest :=
  sys.props.getOrElse("myproject.dockerUpdateLatest", "false").toBoolean
```

Then you start sbt like this:
`sbt -J-Dmyproject.dockerUpdateLatest=true docker:publish`

But I think a more elegant solution is to just check if the version you're building is a snapshot version.

```
dockerUpdateLatest := ! isSnapshot.value
```